Setting a Mariadb session variable in JDBC does not work
The following works in DBeaver but not in JDBC:
SET @@TIMESTAMP=UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2018-01-19 04:14:07.999999");
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
Result: 2018-01-19 04:14:07.000000

Mariadb 10.11.6-MariaDB-0+deb
mariadb-java-client: 3.3.3
openjdk 19.0.2

JDBC:
final String timestampString = transientInstance.getValidFrom()
                                                .format(DateTimeFormat);
try (Connection con = datasource.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement timestampStatement = con.prepareStatement("SET @@SESSION.TIMESTAMP=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(?);");
     PreparedStatement readTimestampStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL")) {

    LOGGER.atDebug()
          .addArgument(timestampString)
          .log("Setting @TIMESTAMP to {}");
//    Result: Setting @TIMESTAMP to 2024-07-26 09:07:73.730084000
    timestampStatement.setString(1, timestampString);
    timestampStatement.execute();
    timestampStatement.close();
    readTimestampStatement.execute();
    final ResultSet resultSetReadTimestamp = readTimestampStatement.getResultSet();
    resultSetReadTimestamp.next();
    LOGGER.atInfo()
          .addArgument(resultSetReadTimestamp.getObject(1))
          .log("Timestamp: {}");
//    Result: Timestamp: 2024-07-29 09:58:27.0  - expected: 2024-07-26 09:07:73.730084000
    resultSetReadTimestamp.close();


Given DBeaver uses JDBC, it is not JDBC that is the problem. Likely you need to disable auto-commit for what you're doing, or something similar.

It is not a JDBC problem. Probably you use a wrong query. Also you didnt test results properly, that's why you can' t get any meaningful results. JDBC is primarily behave using a driver which is provided by the application.

In SQL, string literals are necessarily included in single quotes. However, the code snippet in this question has double quotes. There are 3 possible options: [1] That was a typo, and the SET SQL statement sent via DBeaver actually has single quotes. In which case, perhaps edit the question and fix this. [2] You are really supposed to use identifier escapes (that's what double quotes do in SQL) here. In which case, That ? in your prepared statement cannot fill that in then, you can only set literals that way!, or...

[3] I'm missing something. I'm not familiar with DBeaver and not familiar with MySQL/MaraiDB, Hence why I'm not posting this as an answer.

Given that you get no errors, the first thing I'd do is to turn off autocommit. That's a good idea in general, and I bet those SET variables may well disappear once you commit. Run con.setAutoCommit(false) at the top of your try-with block, then report back if that fixes the issue.

Thanks for your replies!
The problem was a wrong DateTime Format.
The problem is that the database didn't throw an exception! Very dangerous!
FYI: Double quotes work - here is the working statement:
PreparedStatement timestampStatement = con.prepareStatement("SET @@TIMESTAMP=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(\"%s\");"
             .formatted(timestampString));


Great to know this.
